# All my Top Ribbon Menu Images are missing after upgrading to Office365 SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

This site was a custom SharePoint site developed in SharePoint 2010. After my company did an upgrade to 2013, most of the layouts and CSS styles were messed up. I have managed to put the homepage back to its original state but now I've got stuck with this issue of missing menu images from the top ribbon. The new gear icon(site action) is missing as well. here's a picture below of my ribbon. Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Check your Language ID (in the iCON image Path) ...

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a lot of the tags and classes changed between 2010 and 2013 (in fact, if memory serves, a big chunk of those changes came in an early CU that basically destroyed everybody's custom branding just a few months after the product was released). You are almost certainly going to need to rebrand your site for 2013.

Fortunately, there is a great new tool to help you with that: the Design Manager. You've probably heard that Designer did away with the WYSIWIG control. It did in large part because that thing never really worked all that well for customized branding. However, the Design Manager now provides you with a pretty quick and easy way to see where all of the zones are and even creates an HTML version of your masterpage to allow for pretty quick edits (it's not a panacea because it gets around adding ASP.NET objects by wrapping them in comment blocks, but it does what it does fairly well and even has a tool that will auto-produce a lot of those comment blocks for you). And once you create one in a publishing site, there's a tool that will automatically wrap up all your masterpages, site assets, scripts, and CSS into one .wsp file you can then deploy into your integration, QA, and production environments.

Answer (score 0):

I've almost figured this one out. It's due to a CSS tag

```
Img {
Max-Width 100% ;
}
```

I fixed it with this CSS:

```
/* Top Bar Fix */
.ms-cui-topBar2 img
{
max-width:none;
}

/* Edit Bar Fix */
.ms-cui-tabContainer img
{
max-width:none;
} 

/* Add Item Fix */
.ms-addnew img 
{
max-width:none;
}
```

But I have not yet been able to figure out the gear icon. If you find that one let me know!

Comment: Can you change master page to default instead of your custom master page to see if gear icon is coming there